# LocalStorage Item Issue in Angular 2

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have a localStorage item called 'loggedInUser' for storing logged in Clients. Now this is how the application works: When the user authenticates into the application, he sees all his clients in a table. Now, when the user clicks on the any of the clients, another authentication is done to authenticate the email of the client the user clicked.

Here is my problem

Comment: If you your component is just calling this service and the service is already set to that data it may appear prior.  You can try to unset it on `ngOnDestroy()` in your component assuming this is done with routing also.

Comment: @Dylan, could you please be much more clearer :)?

Comment: Sorry I'm going on assumption that your have routing for this that would init and destroy a component on each,  does this sound correct?  This is why I think you might clear out your data or at least log to see, each time on destroy.  If you are doing something else like show/hide, then there is probably a different reason your data persists.

Comment: ooh okay.. i am getting a point there. This is what happens. when the client is authenticated and value is stored in the localstorage, the stored value is passed to another component to use display the authenticated user

Comment: It sounds like your service just retains the previous value which it should as it's a `singleton` for lack of a better term.  You can use the components `lifecycle hooks` to handle when to show / remove this data.